# How to repeat program if user says they want to play again?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I've created a program that asks for shoe size. If the shoe size is correct, the user will get a message that says, "You are correct would you like to try again?" They can either answer yes or no. If they select "no" the program will break and they will get another message that says, "Thanks for playing!"

Is there a way to basically force the program to break back into the while loop if the user enters yes as an answer instead of no?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int shoesize = 13;
    int input;
    string answer;

    while (input != shoesize) {
        cout << "Guess my shoe size!";
        cin >> input;

        if (input == shoesize) {
            cout << "You are correct! Thanks for Playing! Would you like to play again? \n";
            cin >> answer;

            if (answer == "no") {
                cout << "Thank you for playing!";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You approach your problem from the wrong side. You don't need to "break back into" loop when user enters `yes`. You need to *`break` out of* the loop if user enters `no`.

Comment: Breaking into a loop is not doable. Better to not leave the loop in the first place.

Comment: It does that already. Only then it checks whether `input != shoesize`, which is still false because it still has the last answer from the user in `input`.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, technically it is doable, but I'd get crucified for even mentioning `goto`, so we can go with "not doable".

Comment: `while (input != shoesize) {` is a bug in the current code because at the first time this code has been hit `input` has not been initialized.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen looks like at least one answer is not as insanity adverse.

Answer (score 1):

Easily the best way to write something that "repeats continuously until you want to quit" is to just do something like this:

```
while(true) {
  .. do something ..
  .. ask "do you want to quit" ..
  if (answer == "yes") {
    break;
  }
}
```

Programmers will instantly recognize the `while(true){}` *"endless"* loop, and look for the `break` statement which – as the name implies, "breaks out of" the innermost loop, ending the "endless" loop.  One nice thing about this design is that you can use the `break` statement in more than one place within the loop as needed.  (Within a function, you can also `return`.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int shoesize = 13;
    string answer;
    int input = 0;

    while (input != shoesize && answer != "no") {
        cout << "Guess my shoe size!";
        cin >> input;

        if (input == shoesize) {
            cout << "You are correct! Thanks for Playing! Would you like to play again? \n";
            cin >> answer;

            if (answer == "no") {
                cout << "Thank you for playing!";
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is no different from wrapping the bulk of the function in another `while` loop. Not what the asker's looking for, I'm aftraid.